# Rails Dynamic Search in a Model

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following model:

Car which has :**year**, :**model** and :**car_brand_id** fields.
CarBrand which has only a :**name** field and has_many :**cars**.

In the view I have a search form with ransack like the following:

```
<%= search_form_for(@q, url: search_result_path) do |f| %>

  <%= f.select(:year_eq, 1960..(Date.today.year+1), {prompt: 'year'}, class: "grey-text") %>
  <%= f.collection_select :car_brand_id_eq, CarBrand.all, :id, :name, {prompt: 'brand'}, class: "grey-text" %>
  <%= f.collection_select :model_eq, Car.models, :model, :model, {prompt: 'model'}, class: "grey-text " %>
  <%= f.button "Search" %>

<% end %>
```

I would like to make the form search dynamic, for example, if a user choose a specific year in the form, the next field (:car_brand_id) only returns the options for select which have the year previously selected, an so on with the next fields. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no "rails" way to do this. You'll have to use Javascript to make an ajax call to your rails server to get the content and then update DOM. Google "javascript ajax," "javascript onchange event" and "changing DOM with javascript" to get started. I recommend using `jquery` if you're familiar with it.  And of course, if you get stuck, you can always come back here with your broken code- we'll be happy to help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a special affinity for questions like this because it took me a LONG time to figure out similar things. So generally it should be like this:

1. Set up your `:car_brand_eq` collection_select with an instance variable that you can update as a result of an ajax call and a class you can reference it with. Change:

   ```
   <%= f.collection_select :car_brand_eq, CarBrand.all...
   ```

   to:

   ```
   <%= f.collection_select :car_brand_eq, @car_brands, :id, :name, {prompt: 'brand'}, class: "grey-text car-brand-collection" %>
   ```
2. Set up your AJAX call:

   Either grab the id of the `<%= f.select(:year_eq...` to use in jquery or add a unique class name to it:

   ```
   <%= f.select(:year_eq, 1960..(Date.today.year+1), {prompt: 'year'}, class: "grey-text year-selector") %>
   ```

   Then the script:

   ```
   <script>
     $(document).on("change", ".year-selector", function () {
       $.ajax({
         url: "/car_brands/search.js",
         // now pass params[:year] as a query string
         data: { year: $(".year-selector").val() },
         type: "GET"
       });
     });
   </script>
   ```
3. Now set up your `search_car_brands_path` route and then the logic in `car_brands_controller.rb`, or whatever other controller you would use:

   **routes.rb** [(an explantion of this routes logic here)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

   ```
   resources :car_brands do
     collection do
       # search_car_brands_path
       get :search
     end
   end
   ```

   **car_brands_controller.rb**

   ```
   ...
   # GET /car_brands/search
   # search_car_brands_path
   def search
     # not knowing how exactly you filter CarBrands by year, I'm guessing:
     @car_brands = CarBrand.where(year: params[:year])
   end
   ```
4. Finally. Now you just need to set up search.js.erb in:

   **views/car_brands/search.js.erb**

   ```
   // grab that car-brand-collection selector from step 1 & update it
   $(".car-brand-collection").html("<%= f.collection_select :car_brand_eq, @car_brands, :id, :name, {prompt: 'brand'}, class: "grey-text car-brand-collection" %>");
   ```

These are the steps. I haven't tested them, but you should be able to work it out from here.